# Where to disable changing titles to lowercase in a .bst file?

Tags: bibtex, capitalization

Using Tufte LaTeX, I stumbled upon lowercased titles such as "This is a title" instead of "This Is a Title".

In my .bib file, there is

```
title = {This Is a Title}
```

I know that double braces help, but I would rather fix the problem than circumvent it.

Thus, this is the full .bst file, and I know it's written in a kind of reverse Polish notation. However, the problem only occurs with article bib items and not books, thus it must be somewhere in the definition of the article function. I suspect `format.title` or `change.case$`.

But I cannot find it!

What do I have to change to keep capitalization in articles?

```
< Deleted some text due to word limit >
FUNCTION {non.stop}
{ duplicate$
   "}" * add.period$
   #-1 #1 substring$ "." =
}

STRINGS {z}
FUNCTION {remove.dots}
{ 'z :=
  ""
  { z empty$ not }
  { z #1 #1 substring$
    z #2 global.max$ substring$ 'z :=
    duplicate$ "." = 'pop$
      { * }
    if$
  }
  while$
}
FUNCTION {new.block.checka}
{ empty$
    'skip$
    'new.block
  if$
}
FUNCTION {new.block.checkb}
{ empty$
  swap$ empty$
  and
    'skip$
    'new.block
  if$
}
FUNCTION {new.sentence.checka}
{ empty$
    'skip$
    'new.sentence
  if$
}
FUNCTION {new.sentence.checkb}
{ empty$
  swap$ empty$
  and
    'skip$
    'new.sentence
  if$
}
FUNCTION {field.or.null}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    'skip$
  if$
}
FUNCTION {emphasize}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "\emph{" swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {tie.or.space.prefix}
{ duplicate$ text.length$ #3 <
    { "~" }
    { " " }
  if$
  swap$
}

FUNCTION {capitalize}
{ "u" change.case$ "t" change.case$ }

FUNCTION {space.word}
{ " " swap$ * " " * }
 % Here are the language-specific definitions for explicit words.
 % Each function has a name bbl.xxx where xxx is the English word.
 % The language selected here is ENGLISH
FUNCTION {bbl.and}
{ "and"}

FUNCTION {bbl.etal}
{ "et~al." }

FUNCTION {bbl.editors}
{ "eds." }

FUNCTION {bbl.editor}
{ "ed." }

FUNCTION {bbl.edby}
{ "edited by" }

FUNCTION {bbl.edition}
{ "edn." }

FUNCTION {bbl.volume}
{ "vol." }

FUNCTION {bbl.of}
{ "of" }

FUNCTION {bbl.number}
{ "no." }

FUNCTION {bbl.nr}
{ "no." }

FUNCTION {bbl.in}
{ "in" }

FUNCTION {bbl.pages}
{ "pp." }

FUNCTION {bbl.page}
{ "p." }

FUNCTION {bbl.chapter}
{ "chap." }

FUNCTION {bbl.techrep}
{ "Tech. Rep." }

FUNCTION {bbl.mthesis}
{ "Master's thesis" }

FUNCTION {bbl.phdthesis}
{ "Ph.D. thesis" }

FUNCTION {bbl.first}
{ "1st" }

FUNCTION {bbl.second}
{ "2nd" }

FUNCTION {bbl.third}
{ "3rd" }

FUNCTION {bbl.fourth}
{ "4th" }

FUNCTION {bbl.fifth}
{ "5th" }

FUNCTION {bbl.st}
{ "st" }

FUNCTION {bbl.nd}
{ "nd" }

FUNCTION {bbl.rd}
{ "rd" }

FUNCTION {bbl.th}
{ "th" }

MACRO {jan} {"Jan."}

MACRO {feb} {"Feb."}

MACRO {mar} {"Mar."}

MACRO {apr} {"Apr."}

MACRO {may} {"May"}

MACRO {jun} {"Jun."}

MACRO {jul} {"Jul."}

MACRO {aug} {"Aug."}

MACRO {sep} {"Sep."}

MACRO {oct} {"Oct."}

MACRO {nov} {"Nov."}

MACRO {dec} {"Dec."}

FUNCTION {eng.ord}
{ duplicate$ "1" swap$ *
  #-2 #1 substring$ "1" =
     { bbl.th * }
     { duplicate$ #-1 #1 substring$
       duplicate$ "1" =
         { pop$ bbl.st * }
         { duplicate$ "2" =
             { pop$ bbl.nd * }
             { "3" =
                 { bbl.rd * }
                 { bbl.th * }
               if$
             }
           if$
          }
       if$
     }
   if$
}

MACRO {acmcs} {"ACM Computing Surveys"}

MACRO {acta} {"Acta Informatica"}

MACRO {cacm} {"Communications of the ACM"}

MACRO {ibmjrd} {"IBM Journal of Research and Development"}

MACRO {ibmsj} {"IBM Systems Journal"}

MACRO {ieeese} {"IEEE Transactions on Software Engineering"}

MACRO {ieeetc} {"IEEE Transactions on Computers"}

MACRO {ieeetcad}
 {"IEEE Transactions on Computer-Aided Design of Integrated Circuits"}

MACRO {ipl} {"Information Processing Letters"}

MACRO {jacm} {"Journal of the ACM"}

MACRO {jcss} {"Journal of Computer and System Sciences"}

MACRO {scp} {"Science of Computer Programming"}

MACRO {sicomp} {"SIAM Journal on Computing"}

MACRO {tocs} {"ACM Transactions on Computer Systems"}

MACRO {tods} {"ACM Transactions on Database Systems"}

MACRO {tog} {"ACM Transactions on Graphics"}

MACRO {toms} {"ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software"}

MACRO {toois} {"ACM Transactions on Office Information Systems"}

MACRO {toplas} {"ACM Transactions on Programming Languages and Systems"}

MACRO {tcs} {"Theoretical Computer Science"}
FUNCTION {bibinfo.check}
{ swap$
  duplicate$ missing$
    {
      pop$ pop$
      ""
    }
    { duplicate$ empty$
        {
          swap$ pop$
        }
        { swap$
          pop$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {bibinfo.warn}
{ swap$
  duplicate$ missing$
    {
      swap$ "missing " swap$ * " in " * cite$ * warning$ pop$
      ""
    }
    { duplicate$ empty$
        {
          swap$ "empty " swap$ * " in " * cite$ * warning$
        }
        { swap$
          pop$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.url}
{ url empty$
    { "" }
    { "\urlprefix\url{" url * "}" * }
  if$
}

STRINGS  { bibinfo}
INTEGERS { nameptr namesleft numnames }

FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 'bibinfo :=
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ {
  's :=
  "" 't :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}"
      format.name$
      bibinfo bibinfo.check
      't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          nameptr #1
          #1 + =
          numnames #2
          > and
            { "others" 't :=
              #1 'namesleft := }
            'skip$
          if$
          namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            {
              numnames #2 >
                { "," * }
                'skip$
              if$
              s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                { 't := }
                { pop$ }
              if$
              t "others" =
                {
                  " " * bbl.etal *
                }
                {
                  bbl.and
                  space.word * t *
                }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
  } if$
}
FUNCTION {format.names.ed}
{
  format.names
}
FUNCTION {format.authors}
{ author "author" format.names
}
FUNCTION {get.bbl.editor}
{ editor num.names$ #1 > 'bbl.editors 'bbl.editor if$ }

FUNCTION {format.editors}
{ editor "editor" format.names duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      " " *
      get.bbl.editor
   "(" swap$ * ")" *
      *
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.note}
{
 note empty$
    { "" }
    { note #1 #1 substring$
      duplicate$ "{" =
        'skip$
        { output.state mid.sentence =
          { "l" }
          { "u" }
        if$
        change.case$
        }
      if$
      note #2 global.max$ substring$ * "note" bibinfo.check
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title
  "title" bibinfo.check
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      "\enquote{" swap$ *
      "}, " *
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {end.quote.title}
{ title empty$
    'skip$
    { before.all 'output.state := }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
{ newline$
  "\bibitem{" write$
  cite$ write$
  "}" write$
  newline$
  ""
  before.all 'output.state :=
}

FUNCTION {n.dashify}
{
  't :=
  ""
    { t empty$ not }
    { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" =
        { t #1 #2 substring$ "--" = not
            { "--" *
              t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
            }
            {   { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" = }
                { "-" *
                  t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
                }
              while$
            }
          if$
        }
        { t #1 #1 substring$ *
          t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
        }
      if$
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {word.in}
{ bbl.in
  " " * }

FUNCTION {format.date}
{
  ""
  duplicate$ empty$
  year  "year"  bibinfo.check duplicate$ empty$
    { swap$ 'skip$
        { "there's a month but no year in " cite$ * warning$ }
      if$
      *
    }
    { swap$ 'skip$
        {
          swap$
          " " * swap$
        }
      if$
      *
    }
  if$
  duplicate$ empty$
    'skip$
    {
      before.all 'output.state :=
    ", " swap$ *
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.btitle}
{ title "title" bibinfo.check
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      emphasize
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {either.or.check}
{ empty$
    'pop$
    { "can't use both " swap$ * " fields in " * cite$ * warning$ }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.bvolume}
{ volume empty$
    { "" }
    { bbl.volume volume tie.or.space.prefix
      "volume" bibinfo.check * *
      series "series" bibinfo.check
      duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
        { swap$ bbl.of space.word * swap$
          emphasize * }
      if$
      "volume and number" number either.or.check
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.number.series}
{ volume empty$
    { number empty$
        { series field.or.null }
        { series empty$
            { number "number" bibinfo.check }
        { output.state mid.sentence =
            { bbl.number }
            { bbl.number capitalize }
          if$
          number tie.or.space.prefix "number" bibinfo.check * *
          bbl.in space.word *
          series "series" bibinfo.check *
        }
      if$
    }
      if$
    }
    { "" }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {is.num}
{ chr.to.int$
  duplicate$ "0" chr.to.int$ < not
  swap$ "9" chr.to.int$ > not and
}

FUNCTION {extract.num}
{ duplicate$ 't :=
  "" 's :=
  { t empty$ not }
  { t #1 #1 substring$
    t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
    duplicate$ is.num
      { s swap$ * 's := }
      { pop$ "" 't := }
    if$
  }
  while$
  s empty$
    'skip$
    { pop$ s }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {convert.edition}
{ extract.num "l" change.case$ 's :=
  s "first" = s "1" = or
    { bbl.first 't := }
    { s "second" = s "2" = or
        { bbl.second 't := }
        { s "third" = s "3" = or
            { bbl.third 't := }
            { s "fourth" = s "4" = or
                { bbl.fourth 't := }
                { s "fifth" = s "5" = or
                    { bbl.fifth 't := }
                    { s #1 #1 substring$ is.num
                        { s eng.ord 't := }
                        { edition 't := }
                      if$
                    }
                  if$
                }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
  t
}

FUNCTION {format.edition}
{ edition duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      convert.edition
      output.state mid.sentence =
        { "l" }
        { "t" }
      if$ change.case$
      "edition" bibinfo.check
      " " * bbl.edition *
    }
  if$
}
INTEGERS { multiresult }
FUNCTION {multi.page.check}
{ 't :=
  #0 'multiresult :=
    { multiresult not
      t empty$ not
      and
    }
    { t #1 #1 substring$
      duplicate$ "-" =
      swap$ duplicate$ "," =
      swap$ "+" =
      or or
        { #1 'multiresult := }
        { t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't := }
      if$
    }
  while$
  multiresult
}
FUNCTION {format.pages}
{ pages duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    { duplicate$ multi.page.check
        {
          bbl.pages swap$
          n.dashify
        }
        {
          bbl.page swap$
        }
      if$
      tie.or.space.prefix
      "pages" bibinfo.check
      * *
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.journal.pages}
{ pages duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
    { swap$ duplicate$ empty$
        { pop$ pop$ format.pages }
        {
          ", " *
          swap$
          n.dashify
          pages multi.page.check
            'bbl.pages
            'bbl.page
          if$
          swap$ tie.or.space.prefix
          "pages" bibinfo.check
          * *
          *
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume field.or.null
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      "volume" bibinfo.check
    }
  if$
  number "number" bibinfo.check duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      swap$ duplicate$ empty$
        { "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * warning$ }
        'skip$
      if$
      swap$
      "(" swap$ * ")" *
    }
  if$ *
}

FUNCTION {format.chapter.pages}
{ chapter empty$
    { "" }
    { type empty$
        { bbl.chapter }
        { type "l" change.case$
          "type" bibinfo.check
        }
      if$
      chapter tie.or.space.prefix
      "chapter" bibinfo.check
      * *
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.booktitle}
{
  booktitle "booktitle" bibinfo.check
  emphasize
}
FUNCTION {format.in.ed.booktitle}
{ format.booktitle duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      editor "editor" format.names.ed duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
        {
          bbl.edby
          " " * swap$ *
          swap$
          "," *
          " " * swap$
          * }
      if$
      word.in swap$ *
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {empty.misc.check}
{ author empty$ title empty$ howpublished empty$
  month empty$ year empty$ note empty$
  and and and and and
    { "all relevant fields are empty in " cite$ * warning$ }
    'skip$
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.thesis.type}
{ type duplicate$ empty$
    'pop$
    { swap$ pop$
      "t" change.case$ "type" bibinfo.check
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.tr.number}
{ number "number" bibinfo.check
  type duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ bbl.techrep }
    'skip$
  if$
  "type" bibinfo.check
  swap$ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "t" change.case$ }
    { tie.or.space.prefix * * }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.article.crossref}
{
  key duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$
      journal duplicate$ empty$
        { "need key or journal for " cite$ * " to crossref " * crossref * warning$ }
        { "journal" bibinfo.check emphasize word.in swap$ * }
      if$
    }
    { word.in swap$ * " " *}
  if$
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}
FUNCTION {format.crossref.editor}
{ editor #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
  "editor" bibinfo.check
  editor num.names$ duplicate$
  #2 >
    { pop$
      "editor" bibinfo.check
      " " * bbl.etal
      *
    }
    { #2 <
        'skip$
        { editor #2 "{ff }{vv }{ll}{ jj}" format.name$ "others" =
            {
              "editor" bibinfo.check
              " " * bbl.etal
              *
            }
            {
             bbl.and space.word
              * editor #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
              "editor" bibinfo.check
              *
            }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.book.crossref}
{ volume duplicate$ empty$
    { "empty volume in " cite$ * "'s crossref of " * crossref * warning$
      pop$ word.in
    }
    { bbl.volume
      swap$ tie.or.space.prefix "volume" bibinfo.check * * bbl.of space.word *
    }
  if$
  editor empty$
  editor field.or.null author field.or.null =
  or
    { key empty$
        { series empty$
            { "need editor, key, or series for " cite$ * " to crossref " *
              crossref * warning$
              "" *
            }
            { series emphasize * }
          if$
        }
        { key * }
      if$
    }
    { format.crossref.editor * }
  if$
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}
FUNCTION {format.incoll.inproc.crossref}
{
  editor empty$
  editor field.or.null author field.or.null =
  or
    { key empty$
        { format.booktitle duplicate$ empty$
            { "need editor, key, or booktitle for " cite$ * " to crossref " *
              crossref * warning$
            }
            { word.in swap$ * }
          if$
        }
        { word.in key * " " *}
      if$
    }
    { word.in format.crossref.editor * " " *}
  if$
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}
FUNCTION {format.org.or.pub}
{ 't :=
  ""
  address empty$ t empty$ and
    'skip$
    {
      t empty$
        { address "address" bibinfo.check *
        }
        { t *
          address empty$
            'skip$
            { ", " * address "address" bibinfo.check * }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.publisher.address}
{ publisher "publisher" bibinfo.warn format.org.or.pub
}

FUNCTION {format.organization.address}
{ organization "organization" bibinfo.check format.org.or.pub
}

FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  format.title "title" output.check
  end.quote.title
  crossref missing$
    {
      journal
      remove.dots
      "journal" bibinfo.check
      emphasize
      "journal" output.check
      format.vol.num.pages output
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  format.journal.pages
  format.url output
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}
FUNCTION {book}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check
    }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
        { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      format.publisher.address output
    }
    {
      format.book.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
  format.date "year" output.check
  format.url output
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}
FUNCTION {booklet}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  format.title "title" output.check
  end.quote.title
  howpublished "howpublished" bibinfo.check output
  address "address" bibinfo.check output
  format.date output
  format.url output
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {inbook}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check
    }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
        { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    {
      format.publisher.address output
      format.bvolume output
      format.chapter.pages "chapter and pages" output.check
      format.number.series output
    }
    {
      format.chapter.pages "chapter and pages" output.check
      format.book.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
  format.date "year" output.check
  format.pages "pages" output.check
  format.url output
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {incollection}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  format.title "title" output.check
  end.quote.title
  crossref missing$
    { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
      format.publisher.address output
      format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      format.chapter.pages output
      format.edition output
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
      format.chapter.pages output
    }
  if$
  format.pages "pages" output.check
  format.url output
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}
FUNCTION {inproceedings}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  format.title "title" output.check
  end.quote.title
  crossref missing$
    { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
      publisher empty$
        { format.organization.address output }
        { organization "organization" bibinfo.check output
          format.publisher.address output
        }
      if$
      format.date "year" output.check
      format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  format.pages "pages" output.check
  format.url output
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}
FUNCTION {conference} { inproceedings }
FUNCTION {manual}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { organization "organization" bibinfo.check
      duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
        { output
          address "address" bibinfo.check output
        }
      if$
    }
    { format.authors output.nonnull }
  if$
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  author empty$
    { organization empty$
        {
          address "address" bibinfo.check output
        }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
    {
      organization "organization" bibinfo.check output
      address "address" bibinfo.check output
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
  format.date output
  format.url output
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {mastersthesis}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  format.btitle
  "title" output.check
  bbl.mthesis format.thesis.type output.nonnull
  school "school" bibinfo.warn output
  address "address" bibinfo.check output
  format.date "year" output.check
  format.url output
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {misc}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  format.title output
  end.quote.title
  howpublished "howpublished" bibinfo.check output
  format.date output
  format.url output
  format.note output
  fin.entry
  empty.misc.check
}
FUNCTION {phdthesis}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  format.btitle
  "title" output.check
  bbl.phdthesis format.thesis.type output.nonnull
  school "school" bibinfo.warn output
  address "address" bibinfo.check output
  format.date "year" output.check
  format.url output
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {proceedings}
{ output.bibitem
  editor empty$
    { organization "organization" bibinfo.check output
    }
    { format.editors output.nonnull }
  if$
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  format.bvolume output
  format.number.series output
  editor empty$
    { publisher empty$
        'skip$
        {
          format.publisher.address output
        }
      if$
    }
    { publisher empty$
        {
          format.organization.address output }
        {
          organization "organization" bibinfo.check output
          format.publisher.address output
        }
      if$
     }
  if$
      format.date "year" output.check
  format.url output
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {techreport}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  format.btitle
  "title" output.check
  format.tr.number output.nonnull
  institution "institution" bibinfo.warn output
  address "address" bibinfo.check output
  format.date "year" output.check
  format.url output
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {unpublished}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  format.title "title" output.check
  end.quote.title
  format.date output
  format.url output
  format.note "note" output.check
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {default.type} { misc }
READ
STRINGS { longest.label }
INTEGERS { number.label longest.label.width }
FUNCTION {initialize.longest.label}
{ "" 'longest.label :=
  #1 'number.label :=
  #0 'longest.label.width :=
}
FUNCTION {longest.label.pass}
{ number.label int.to.str$ 'label :=
  number.label #1 + 'number.label :=
  label width$ longest.label.width >
    { label 'longest.label :=
      label width$ 'longest.label.width :=
    }
    'skip$
  if$
}
EXECUTE {initialize.longest.label}
ITERATE {longest.label.pass}
FUNCTION {begin.bib}
{ preamble$ empty$
    'skip$
    { preamble$ write$ newline$ }
  if$
  "\begin{thebibliography}{"  longest.label  * "}" *
  write$ newline$
  "\newcommand{\enquote}[1]{``#1''}"
  write$ newline$
  "\expandafter\ifx\csname url\endcsname\relax"
  write$ newline$
  "  \def\url#1{\texttt{#1}}\fi"
  write$ newline$
  "\expandafter\ifx\csname urlprefix\endcsname\relax\def\urlprefix{URL }\fi"
  write$ newline$
}
EXECUTE {begin.bib}
EXECUTE {init.state.consts}
ITERATE {call.type$}
FUNCTION {end.bib}
{ newline$
  "\end{thebibliography}" write$ newline$
}
EXECUTE {end.bib}
```

Comment: The internal function that changes case is indeed `change.case$`. Since `"t" change.case$` expects a string at the top of the stack and returns a string (modified according to the rules), I guess that just removing all occurrences of `"t" change.case$` where a title is concerned should do.

Comment: Thanks — I read the documentation of `change.case$`, so I thought if I changed all "t" values to "u" that would at least change something, but it does not seem to.

Comment: what `\bibliographystyle` command do you have in your document? As Heiko says in his answer, the code shown doesn't lower case article titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Too long for a comment.</sub>

The following example uses [`tufte.bst`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tufte-latex/tufte.bst), which shows that the style does **not** change the capitalization of the title of an article:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{test-tufte.bib}
@article{a,
  title={The Title of an Article},
  author={John Doe},
  journal={The Journal Name},
  year=2016
}
@book{b,
  title={The Title of a Book},
  author={Ute Mustermann},
  publisher={Publisher},
  year=2016,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\begin{document}
\cite{a, b}
\bibliography{test-tufte}
\bibliographystyle{tufte}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I now see that `tufte.bst` is not the reason for the observed behaviour. Still looking for it, though ... According to `sample-book.tex` from the Tufte package, one uses `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}`. Changing that to `tufte` causes an error that the bibliography is not compatible with author-year citations ...

Comment: Wait, does that mean that `tufte.bst` isn't even used?

Comment: Yeah! Thanks to you, I understood how that works, read the correct part in *Tame the BeaST*, made a custom `plainnat.bst` with the `format.title` function adjusted ... and now it works! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Replace function `format.title` with:

```
FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title empty$
    { "" }
    { title }
  if$
}
```

Comment: It removes the quotes from the original definition (`\enquote`), but I do not see that the original `format.title` changes the capitalization.